# How to prevent ungraceful shutdown of applications ran in my batchfile

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos, shutdown

I am developing a backup algorithm similar to Time Machine ("continuous backup" software). I am successful in doing it via batchfile (command prompt). It runs almost every 3 minutes for less than a minute each "round". The batchfile is running in a command prompt window (which I can hide if my code is already doing fine.)

The only problem I encounter is when shutting down, I have to wait for the batchfile to finish its "round" before I could click the shutdown button (or else, pressing shutdown at any other time will screw up things--dos commands will be terminated in the midst of anything, thus the algorithm is ruined). I want to do it automatically, that is, I can click the shutdown button, then my batchfile should wait for the "round" to finish, the dos commands should not be terminated, then only after the "round" should it permit the machine to shut down.

The dos programs that I use which are terminated ungracefully are: ln(found on web--used to hardlink files), copy, move (plus things like for loops, dir command etc are ruined).

How can I prevent ungraceful shutdown of these applications in my batchfiles? (and any other application that I run?)

I have tried running it as a different user, but just the same, the applications are terminated on shutdown. I thought of running the command in Visual Basic while using a "prevent shutdown" code in VB, but only the VB app is not terminated, the batchfile I ran inside VB app as well as the application it runs are terminated just the same.

Help

ccxzy

Comment: I know that in Linux, there's a way to trap kill, ctrl+C, ... so the script doesn't react to it and you're able to write a program that gets activated when the trap is activated. Maybe worth looking at?

Comment: What does the "prevent shutdown" VB code actually do? Does it cancel the shutdown process or simply prevent the VB application itself from being terminated (thus merely blocking the overall shutdown process)? I wonder if it could be changed so as to stop the initiated shutdown if necessary, wait for the "round" to finish, *then* shutdown the system automatically.

Comment: @AndriyM it prevents the VB application from being terminated. I'm thinking about it right now. Maybe, the thing there is I should cancel the shutdown process fast enough before it kills some of my applications which is running in progress (thereby ruining my algorithm). I'm thinking that there will always be a lag before the shutdown is stopped, therefore, there is always a risk that something in my algorithm will fail.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense, there is such a risk, I'm afraid. And, considering that the desired effect is neither guaranteed nor predictable with this approach, "we are back to square one", I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means clean, but this is the only way I can think to do it.

External batch file:

```
    @ECHO OFF
    :loop
        if exist %temp%\done.flg (
            if exist %temp%\shutdown.flg shutdown -s -f -t 0 && del /Q %temp%\shutdown.flg
            del /Q %temp%\done.flg
            exit
        )
        shutdown -a > NUL 2>&1 && echo shutdown detected > %temp%\shutdown.flg
        ping localhost -n 2 > NUL 2>&1
    goto loop
```

Original batch file:

```
    start "" "path\to\shutdown\stopper.bat"
    :: back up code here
    echo done > %temp%\done.flg
```

This would try to stop a shutdown every two seconds, if it succeeds it will shut down after.